# Stopping playback of mp3

Tags: android, button, onclick, media-player

I'm making an application that uses mp3's and I have a very simple question that I have been unable to find the answer for. I have a `grid` of `buttons` and each click plays an mp3:

```
final MediaPlayer mpButton1Click = MediaPlayer.create(mContext,
            R.raw.my_mp3);
```

with:

```
if(position == 0){
            mpButton1Click.start();
        }
```

The `position` variable is for the location on the grid. My question is, how do I get an mp3 that is currently playing to stop when a new button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

All your code need is

```
mpButton1Click.stop();
```

Which will stop the player

Comment: Well the thing is that is one button on one page, I have multiple pages with another variable called `mpButton1Click`. I'm looking for a general stop playback function that way I don't have to say `mpButton1Click.stop();` `mpButton2Click.stop();` `mpButton3Click.stop();` ect. on every play call

Comment: @rsayles3 you could do is start as a service and then you can stop the service anytime you want. but yes you will need to stop services everywhere